# What is azimuthal symmetry?

Tags: electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

What is azimuthal symmetry? When to use azimuthal symmetry and and how to know whether the problem has azimuthal symmetry or not?

Comment: See especially this explanation given in the linked answer: "From my understanding of azimuth, it describes the angle ϕ in cylindrical or spherical coordinates. Therefore I'd say that the cylindrical and azimuthal symmetry are the same thing: The object is invariant under arbitrary rotations around the x-axis."

Comment: It means to say that if i am going to use azimuthal symmetry, it is the same with cylindrical?

Answer (score 1):

Azimuthal or cylindrical symmetry is symmetry around a straight line. Spherical symmetry is symmetry around a point.